# Adicionando mais de uma opção no produto pela api shopify

Tags: php, json

Estou fazendo a integração com o Shopify, mas não consigo por nenhuma forma por mim encontrado adicionar mais de uma 'option' no produto utilizando a API.
A documentação do shopify é muito ruim!

Exemplo mal sucedido:

```
"options" => array(
    array(
       "name"=> "Cor",
       "position" => 1
    ),
    array(
       "name"=> "Tamanho",
       "position" => 2
    )
),
```

Retorna o seguinte cabeçalho / erro:

```
array(
'headers' => array(
    'status' => 'HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity',
    'Server' => 'nginx',
    'Date' => 'Fri, 13 Apr 2018 20',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Transfer-Encoding' => 'chunked',
    'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
    'X-Sorting-Hat-PodId' => '56',
    'X-Sorting-Hat-PodId-Cached' => '0',
    'X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId' => '2120646713',
    'X-Sorting-Hat-Section' => 'pod',
    'X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId-Cached' => '0',
    'Referrer-Policy' => 'origin-when-cross-origin',
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'DENY',
    'X-ShopId' => '2120646713',
    'X-ShardId' => '56',
    'X-Stats-UserId' => '0',
    'X-Stats-ApiClientId' => '2344784',
    'X-Stats-ApiPermissionId' => '29651009593',
    'HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT' => '1/40',
    'X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit' => '1/40',
    'Strict-Transport-Security' => 'max-age=7889238',
    'X-Request-Id' => '3ae5cd54-ffd5-4eaa-95de-f8884b14bd4f',
    'Content-Security-Policy' => 'default-src 'self' data',
    'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff',
    'X-Download-Options' => 'noopen',
    'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies' => 'none',
    'X-XSS-Protection' => '1; mode=block; report=/xss-report?source%5Baction%5D=create&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproducts&source%5Bsection%5D=admin_api&source%5Buuid%5D=3ae5cd54-ffd5-4eaa-95de-f8884b14bd4f',
    'X-Dc' => 'ash,cloud2',
    'Via' => '1.1 google',
    'Alt-Svc' => 'clear'
),
'response' => '{"errors":{"options":["is invalid"],"name":["can't be blank"]}}'
)
```

quando envio assim (abaixo), é criado um 'option' e se eu tentar adicionar outra da mesma forma utilizando a solicitação PUT, ele sobrescreve a existente, mesmo eu informando uma nova posição.

```
"options" => 
    array(
       "name"=> "Cor",
       "position" => 1
    ),
```

ALGUÉM CONSEGUI ME DA UMA LUZ?

Comment: Consegue fazer um POST ao invés de PUT?

Comment: O PUT por padrão é utilizado para atualizações.

Comment: Faço o POST sem problema, mais o POST só consigo adicionar uma option, e quando utilizo o PUT para atualizar o produto, adicionando outra option, ele atualiza a existente, a tag 'position', serve para informa qual option é, tem um limite de 3.

Comment: No link https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/options-error-when-creating-product-via-post-179779 o usuário @RyanMarshall relatou que o problema estava na forma que ele estava fazendo a requisição.

Comment: Olá Valdeir, agradeço sua ajuda, de acordo com o link que você me enviou, eu estou fazendo exatamente da forma indicada, usando a solicitação json... mais por fim o erro permanece!